# Removing unwanted data from class to save to the database

Tags: php

I have the following simple class:

```
class message {
    
    public $message;
    public $type;

    public $timestamp;
    private $types = [null, "success", "danger", "warning", "info", "primary"];

    public function __construct(string $message, string $type = "success") {
        
        $this->timestamp = time();

        if(in_array(strtolower($type), $this->types)) {
            $this->type = strtolower($type);
        } else {
            $this->type = null;
        }

        $this->message = $message;
    }
}
```

All these messages give the user response from the page, such as 'Successfully saved to database' etc.

I'd like to save the messages to the database, however I dont need to save the `private` property each time, as that's just validating the message type to make sure all added messages fit into the correct available categories.  Really I only want to save the `$message`, `$type`, and `$timestamp`.  I think it'd take up a lot of unnecessary space in the database with 50k entries of messages and the `$type` set each time.

I tried unsetting it, but of course its a private property.  What's a good work aroundhere? Shall i just have my three values in an array and be done with it? Is there any other solution?

Comment: This needs to be handled with either the thing that is inserting it into the database, or if present, the thing that is serializing this. Can you post that?

Comment: As your `$type` property is `public`, it can be set by any class to any value they want.

Comment: Is it an option to make `$types` a static field or is it required that different `message` objects have different `$types` values?

Answer (score 1):

if your serializing the class use __serialize() , this method return custom array for serialization. example:

```
class test{
    public $name ;
    public $type ;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = "test";
        $this->type = "type";
    }
    function __serialize()
    {
        return [$this->type];
    }
}
```

in this example `$name` variable is skipped.